# How to display a base64 jpeg image correctly?

Tags: html, image, base64, screenshot

I've the following problem:

I want to display a screenshot of an other website (I used GoogleAPI to realize that), but something goes wrong.

I use Jquery to get the "screenshot-code" from the following site: https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed?url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions&screenshot=true

Then I try this, but the image does not get displayed:

```
<img style="width: 300px; height: 300px;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,_9j_4AAQSkZJR...............aKs3c__Z" />
```

Comment: What does your browsers error console say? Most likely the encoding is wrong, since the syntax looks fine. Please post the encoding step you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s [URL-safe base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications); replace `-` with `+` and `_` with `/` to convert it to normal base64 for use in a data URI.